# convert java string format date pattern to javascript patterns

Tags: javascript, java, pattern-matching

I have a rest service that send me a java pattern for date formating :

Like this : `%1$td/%1$tm/%1$tY`

is there a simple way to convert this pattern to javascript date formating pattern :

Like this `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: I think it would be the faster solution to make your own converter for this case than to look for it.

Comment: How is this pattern created by Java?